# argument convert in class

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments, converters

I have the following code:

```
    template<class TDataType> class PassData
{
public:

    PassData(int Id,
        const Kratos::Variable<TDataType>& rVariable,
        const TDataType& Value) : mId(Id),
        mVariable(rVariable),
        mValue(Value){}
    void SetProperties()
    {
        mpModeler->SetProperties(mId, mVariable, mValue);
    }
    int mId;
    Kratos::Variable<TDataType> mVariable;
    TDataType mValue;
};
```

...

```
        template<class TDataType>
        void SetProperties(IndexType PropertiesId,
            const Variable<TDataType>& rVariable,
            double* value,int size)
        {
            std::vector<double> v;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)v.push_back(value[i]);
            PassData<std::vector<double>> S = PassData<std::vector<double>>(PropertiesId, rVariable,v);
            S.SetProperties();
        }
```

The following errors displayed when compiling:

```
Error   7   error C2665: 'Kratos::PassData<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::PassData' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types   
Error   8   error C2512: 'Kratos::PassData<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>>' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

Could anyone help me to take a look at it?

Thanks,

Tang Laoya

Answer (score 0):

You have constructor

```
PassData(int Id, const Kratos::Variable<TDataType>& rVariable, const DataType& Value)
```

Then you create your PassData object like this

```
PassData<std::vector<double>>(PropertiesId, rVariable,v);
```

where PropertiesId is of type IndexType (?)

rVariable is of type const Variable& (it's OK)

v is of type std::vector (?)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply. Yes. I found if the constructor is PassData(const DataType& Value) and create PassData object like this PassData<std::vector<double>>(v); the object create is OK.

Comment: could anyone help me to take a look at the problem? Thanks

Comment: even I changed 'IndexType PropertiesId' to 'int PropertiesId', the errors are still the same, could anyone help me to take a look at the problem? Thanks